# Please help me with simple question about material_ui

Tags: material-ui

I just created a react app and installed material ui and in public folder I have include link to roboto font, but it is not applied.

I see only system font (dejVu serif ). If I have override for example muiToolbar and type here fonfamaly roboto it is works, but in default as I wrote it doesn't. How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

To add a font to react regardless of using material-ui or not, You need to add the CDN of the font inside the index.html file, or You can import it using CSS.
[Here is a helpful resource for you](https://medium.com/@weberzt/importing-a-google-font-into-your-react-app-using-material-ui-773760ded532)

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap" />

In fact of the matter I type it in index.html how  prescribein  in instruction but  it nothing work

Comment: link at index.html adding and 
code is simple and similar to this below . I dont thinck that problem with it .. But then what the problem ?


`<code>import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import AppBar from "@material-ui/core/AppBar";
import Toolbar from "@material-ui/core/Toolbar";

function App() {
  return (
    <>
    <AppBar>
      <Toolbar>Toolbar</Toolbar>
    </AppBar>
    </>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
document.getElementById("root")
); </code>`

Comment: Focus  is if i type <Toolbar/> Text </Toolbar/> i  get system  font . if <Button/> Text <Button/> i get Roboto /  ..

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a custom theme file, a file that you customized the application theme?
Check the typography field in that file, maybe some other fonts were added there without your understanding.

Here is the default theme typography field:

```
typography: Object

    htmlFontSize: 16
    pxToRem: f ()
    round: f S()
    fontFamily: ""Roboto", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif"
    fontSize: 14
    fontWeightLight: 300
    fontWeightRegular: 400
    fontWeightMedium: 500
    fontWeightBold: 700

h1: Object

    fontFamily: ""Roboto", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif"
    fontWeight: 300
    fontSize: "6rem"
    lineHeight: 1.167
    letterSpacing: "-0.01562em"

h2: fontFamily: ""Roboto", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif"
    fontWeight: 300
    fontSize: "3.75rem"
    lineHeight: 1.2
    letterSpacing: "-0.00833em"

h3: Object

    fontFamily: ""Roboto", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif"
    fontWeight: 400
    fontSize: "3rem"
    lineHeight: 1.167
    letterSpacing: "0em"

h4: Object

    fontFamily: ""Roboto", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif"
    fontWeight: 400
    fontSize: "2.125rem"
    lineHeight: 1.235
    letterSpacing: "0.00735em"

h5: Object

    fontFamily: ""Roboto", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif"
    fontWeight: 400
    fontSize: "1.5rem"
    lineHeight: 1.334
    letterSpacing: "0em"

h6: Object

    fontFamily: ""Roboto", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif"
    fontWeight: 500
    fontSize: "1.25rem"
    lineHeight: 1.6
    letterSpacing: "0.0075em"

subtitle1: Object

    fontFamily: ""Roboto", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif"
    fontWeight: 400
    fontSize: "1rem"
    lineHeight: 1.75
    letterSpacing: "0.00938em"

subtitle2: Object

    fontFamily: ""Roboto", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif"
    fontWeight: 500
    fontSize: "0.875rem"
    lineHeight: 1.57
    letterSpacing: "0.00714em"

body1: Object

    fontFamily: ""Roboto", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif"
    fontWeight: 400
    fontSize: "1rem"
    lineHeight: 1.5
    letterSpacing: "0.00938em"

body2: Object

    fontFamily: ""Roboto", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif"
    fontWeight: 400
    fontSize: "0.875rem"
    lineHeight: 1.43
    letterSpacing: "0.01071em"

button: Object

    fontFamily: ""Roboto", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif"
    fontWeight: 500
    fontSize: "0.875rem"
    lineHeight: 1.75
    letterSpacing: "0.02857em"
    textTransform: "uppercase"

caption: Object

    fontFamily: ""Roboto", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif"
    fontWeight: 400
    fontSize: "0.75rem"
    lineHeight: 1.66
    letterSpacing: "0.03333em"

overline: Object

    fontFamily: ""Roboto", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif"
    fontWeight: 400
    fontSize: "0.75rem"
    lineHeight: 2.66
    letterSpacing: "0.08333em"
    textTransform: "uppercase"
```